# Android sockets: where is answer from server?

Tags: android, sockets

I work with xbmc server. I connect to the server using sockets and create a JSON POST request.
This is my request:

```
{
    "method": "XBMC.GetInfoBooleans",
    "id": "iPad~XBMC.GetInfoBooleans",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": {
        "booleans": [
            "Player.Paused",
            "Player.Playing"
        ]
    }
}
```

And the code:

```
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        if (socket.isConnected()) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connect with server");

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObjectMain = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jsonObjectAdd = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                jsonArray.put("Player.Paused");
                jsonArray.put("Player.Playing");

                jsonObjectAdd.put("booleans", jsonArray);

                jsonObjectMain.put("method", "XBMC.GetInfoBooleans");
                jsonObjectMain.put("id", "iPad~XBMC.GetInfoBooleans");
                jsonObjectMain.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
                jsonObjectMain.put("params", jsonObjectAdd);

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                out.write(jsonObjectMain.toString());
                out.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String inputLine = null;
            String result = "";
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, in.readLine());
                result = result.concat(inputLine);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, result);

            }

        }

        else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Unconnect");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка UnknownHostException");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ошибка IOException");
    }
```

In logs I can see `"Connect with server"`, but I don't see string `"Result"`. In Android manifest I added all permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: is there a very specific need to use sockets ? Why cant u use ``HTTPClient`` to post it to the listening webserver ?

Comment: It isn't a web server. It is a media center, with that need to connect use wi-fi.

Comment: the ``readLine()`` api is a blocking api .It will block till u either get data on the socket or EOF when the socket is closed . I suspect u are not falling into result . You need to see you server side code . Post it here . The problem lies in the server . (Also remove the doubel ``readLine()`` )

Comment: Also u may want to check that the the ``accept()`` on the server side is broken and that the message that you send from the server contains a ``\n`` i.e a newline at the end of the message .

Comment: Socket.isConnected() cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. Don't write meaningless code. It just clutters up the joint.

Comment: Why this code is meaningless? Explain, please.

Comment: Did my answer help you? I noticed this is your first question

Comment: This is my first question on this account. I have 2 account on Stackoverflow. Sorry, but your answer not help me(

Comment: SOLVED! Server have a password. I add in my code authorization data and all work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `while loop` you're reading twice from the stream. Probably you're receiving only one line and when you're trying to read the second line you're getting null or `End of stream`. Change the `while` to:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, inputLine);
    result = result.concat(inputLine);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, result);
}
```

Also, as an improvement: instead of concatenating Strings, you should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: Your answer isn't help me, but it very important answer.

Comment: SOLVED! Server have a password. I add in my code authorization data and all work! Thank you!